# Search terms with "birth_day", "birth_month"

Tags: php

I want to include a search by D.O.B with these fields "birth_day", "birth_month"

```
function search_users($term, $limit = 10, $friends = false) {
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE
    (username LIKE '%{$term}%' OR first_name LIKE '%{$term}%' OR last_name LIKE '%{$term}%' OR email_address LIKE '%{$term}%') AND bannned='0'
 ";
```

Comment: Did you have column like birth_day or birth_month ?

Comment: Yea i do have birth_day and birth_month.... I want to incoporate it into thr search query

Comment: just two or condition like this $sql = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE
    (username LIKE '%{$term}%' OR first_name LIKE '%{$term}%' OR last_name LIKE '%{$term}%' OR email_address LIKE '%{$term}%' OR birth_day ='{$term}' OR birth_month ='{$term}' ) AND bannned='0'";

Comment: I did it like this but its not giving me what i want. I want to be able to search with birth_day AND birth_month simultaneously not just the day or the month.

Comment: Add the AND condition like this $sql = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE
    (username LIKE '%{$term}%' OR first_name LIKE '%{$term}%' OR last_name LIKE '%{$term}%' OR email_address LIKE '%{$term}%' or ( birth_day ='{$term}' AND birth_month ='{$term}') ) AND bannned='0'";

Comment: I just did, it didnt work... Please is there any other option?

Comment: didnt working mean what you mean query have error ? or not fetching the value ?

Comment: Its not fetching the value...

Comment: echo $sql; and post it here and copy the query and run it directly into database

Comment: Owk let me try that now. Thanx

Comment: Thanx very much... I did it using the explode method:  $combined = $term;
 $searchfield = explode(" ", $combined);                                                      $sql = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE
        (username LIKE '%{$term}%' OR first_name LIKE '%{$term}%' OR last_name LIKE '%{$term}%' OR email_address LIKE '%{$term}%' OR birth_month LIKE '%{$term}%' OR birth_day LIKE '%{$searchfield[0]}%' ) AND bannned='0'
     ";

Answer (score 1):

```
$combined = $term;
$searchfield = explode(" ", $combined);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE
    (username LIKE '%{$term}%' OR first_name LIKE '%{$term}%' OR last_name LIKE '%{$term}%' OR email_address LIKE '%{$term}%' OR birth_month LIKE '%{$term}%' OR birth_day LIKE '%{$searchfield[0]}%' ) AND bannned='0'
 ";
```